# SQL execution sometimes works

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I have read many answers related to this question and am still looking for a solution. C# ASP MVC4 Navicat (SQL Server 2008) is the environment, and the application is a scanner-label maker. The following statement is called as a parameterized query in C# (slightly modified, yes, it is supposed to be where upc_code = itemnum):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable1(ITEM, UPC, BRAND, DESC, SIZE, PRICE, DIST, SALEPRICE, LOC, LABEL, NEWPRICE, TAX, MARKUP, ALLDISC, DIST2, RECNUMBER, userID, HasBeenDownloaded) 

OUTPUT Inserted.BRAND, Inserted.SIZE, Inserted.PRICE 

SELECT TOP 1 I.ITEM, I.UPC, I.BRAND, I.DESC, I.SIZE, I.PRICE, V.DIST, I.SALEPRICE, @LOCATION, I.LABEL, I.NEWPRICE, I.TAX, I.MARKUP, I.ALLDISC, V.DIST2, @RECNUM, @userID, @HasBeenDownloaded 

FROM MyTable2 I, MyTable3 V 

WHERE I.UPC_CODE = @ITEMNUM AND V.ITEM_NUM = I.ITEM_NUM
```

Everything works flawlessly for about 18 scans (one user, approximately 1 scan every 2 seconds) then the server hangs indefinitely. The server hangs at 18 or so queries even if I scan the same item over-and-over, indicating it is not values in the query.

The C# code does use a reader instead of an executeNonQuery, but only because I require the output to inject into the view:

```
using (IDataReader reader = theCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        retVal.Add("Brand", reader["BRAND"    ].ToString());
                        retVal.Add("Size",  reader["SIZE"     ].ToString());
                        retVal.Add("Price", reader["PRICE"].ToString());
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Remembering that I do not have SQLMS, and I am using Navicat, are there any DBAs out there who can guide me in debugging the issue? Alternatively, are there any programmers who have ideas and-or a better way of retrieving the SQL output values?

Comment: Nothing stands out in the code you're posted.  How's the memory usage on the machine?  Have you tried running it in the debugger to see where it hangs?

Comment: Hello D Stanley, I thought it might be memory, so we added another 2GB (same results). Yes, it hangs right at the reader (i.e., it's the SQL Server response, not VS2012). We're hosted on GoDaddy, but even they aren't that bad. It's a semi-complex SQL insert, but nothing that should hang the system with one user (I would think). I'm wondering if it might be corrupt data or the schema or something, but I do not have the DB specialty to diagnose

Comment: Okay, well, it magically started working, so I'm guessing it's GoDaddy...Thanks guys